# List C# find matching User

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this List on ASP.NET, I want to find the connectionid that is given from textbox, and find the matching user, and write his nick into another textbox. How can I do that?

```
    static List<User> users = new List<User>();
    class User
    {
       public string connectionid { get; set; }
       public string nick { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I want to find connectionid from TextBox1, write the matching User nick into TextBox2
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help.

```
foreach(User _user in users)
{
   if(_user.connectionid == TextBox1.Text)
   {
      TextBox2.Text = _user.nick;
      break;
   }
}
```

UPDATE

Added break statement to exit loop when it finds a match.

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
        string connectionid = GetConnectionid();
        try
        {
            User user = users.Find(u => u.connectionid == connectionid);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             // not found
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
     //I want to find connectionid from TextBox1, write the matching User nick into TextBox2
     string tempid = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
     List <User> data = (from user in users 
                              where user.connectionid == tempid  
                         select user).ToList();

    foreach(User aUser in data)
    {
      TextBox2.Text = aUser .nick;
    }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    //Handle exception
  }
```

Comment: I have two textboxes. one is for entry, the other for display

Comment: Why all the redundant assignments?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to find the first `User` with that `connectionid`.

```
User thisUser = (from user in users
    where user.connectionid == TextBox1.Text.Trim() 
    select user).FirstOrDefault();
if(thisUser != null)
{
   // user was found
   otherBox1.Text = thisUser.nick;
}
```

Comment: You don't need a database to use LINQ. It's C# query language that works on collections.